# navigate on another page in asp.net mvc on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have 2 buttons Edit and Next . I have Action written on controller for the Next button. But how to navigate , where should i have to give action link and its parameters? m using asp.net mvc 2. Is i need to write the JavaScript or JQuery ?

Comment: any updates over this pleasae ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have *SomeAction* in *SomeController*, invoke it so :

> <%= Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "SomeAction", "SomeController" ) %>

but I might not understand your request; if so, please embellish.